How to remove "AppleHLS1" in the output path from "Video On Demand on AWS Foundation" template?
I have few questions while I was following the "Video On Demand on AWS Foundation" solution (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/video-on-demand-on-aws-foundation/solution-overview.html). When I completed the steps, I could see converted media files are generated. But I wanted to configure little more to customize for my needs.
How to configure source, logs, and destination folder name?
When I set the stack name "vod-test" for instance, the generated folders are "vod-test-destinationXXXXX"(XXXX is a hash value), "vod-test-logsXXXX", and "vod-test-sourceXXXX". Where can I define the folder names? For example, I want to remove the hash values in the folder names.
How to configure output path to remove (or rename) the default path "AppleHLS1"?
When media files are exported, those are saved under "vod-test-destinationXXXX/XXXX/AppleHLS1/video.m3u8". I'd like to rename the path "AppleHLS1" to "hsl". Where can I set this value?
If you have solved this, please share it with me. Thank you!

Good question.
The output path & filename parameters are set within the individual MediaConvert job. A job Template can have a path specified (optional). I suggest checking your MediaConvert Console to see what templates have been created by the Foundation workflow you linked.
You can use variables in the output file and folder names including date, time, bitrate, and other common parameters. Those are documented here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/using-variables-in-your-job-settings.html
You can update the template manually, and those changes will apply every subsequent time the template gets used.
You can also load and customize a template on-the-fly using a Lambda function. You can trigger this process using an s3 file event when the source file arrives. That workflow is describe here :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/tutorial-s3-batchops-lambda-mediaconvert-video.html
The Lambda approach is more sophisticated and allows for altering job settings dynamically based on the specifics of the input file provided. By probing the input file with ffprobe then customizing the job settings,  your workflow can handle diverse input types.  The ffmpeg layer for Lambda is documented here: https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/us-east-1/145266761615/ffmpeg-lambda-layer

Thanks for your response! Unfortunately there is no templates created in MediaConvert when I followed the Foundation workflow. I guess it creates Lambda functions? I could see three functions created related to it; JobComplete, CustomResource, and jobSubmit. Any suggestion where I can update the destination folder? Thanks!

Given those choices I would start with  'JobSubmit' and if not there, look at the CustomResource lambda.  One of them will be constructing a job JSON  with the specific source file.  It may be loading a generic job file that is not saved as an official Template, but functions as one (?)    Either way, whichever Lambda builds the job config, is where the output path change should go.

In the 'JobSubmit', there is 'const outputPath = s3://${DESTINATION_BUCKET}/${guid};'. I wonder where is 'AppleHLS1' path is coming from.
